# dynamically updating zone subdomains

Tags: bind, subdomain, lets-encrypt, ddns

I'm running a `bind9` (9.9.5) DNS-server (on Debian/jessie).
I have configured one zone to allow dynamic updates, and would like to add `TXT` records for specific hosts within that zone.

Here's a sample setup (named.conf)

```
zone "example.com" {
    type master;
    notify yes;
    allow-update { key secret-key; };
    file "/etc/bind/db.example.com";
};
```

And the accompanying db.example.com file:

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 604800 ; 1 week
example.com     IN SOA  dns.example.com root.example.com. (
                1          ; serial
                10800      ; refresh (3 hours)
                3600       ; retry (1 hour)
                604800     ; expire (1 week)
                86400      ; minimum (1 day)
                )
            NS  dns.example.org.
            NS  dns1.example.org.
            NS  dns2.example.org.
$ORIGIN example.com.
*           MX  10 mail.example.com.
mail        A   127.0.0.1
http        A   127.0.1.1
```

Using my *secret-key*, I can dynamically add a new record directly in that zone (e.g. create a *TXT* record for `_acme-challenge.example.com`).

However, what I really want to do is add subdomain records for hosts within the zone. E.g. in the zone `example.com`, there is an *A* record `mail.example.com`, and I would like to dynamically add a *TXT* record for `_acme-challenge.mail.example.com`.

Unfortunately, my nameserver doesn't like this and refuses to work with

> secret-key: updating zone 'example.com/IN': update failed: not authoritative for update zone (NOTAUTH)

I *can* add that record manually into the db-file, and it works fine.

```
 _acme-challenge.mail TXT "secretstring"
```

However, i would like to *automate* this (given that this is part of deploying letsencrypt certificates via `DNS-01` challenge), so manually setting the records is not an option.

Any ideas what is going wrong and how I can update my TXT-records automatically?

#### update: the script

the actual update is implemented with python-dnspython, and looks like:

```
update = dns.update.Update("mail.example.com", ...)
update.add("_acme-challenge", 500, "TXT", token)
response = dns.query.udp(update, name_server_ip)
```

Comment: How specifically did you do the update that did not work?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist indeed that might be important; i'm using a [dnspython-based script](https://github.com/eferdman/dnspython-hook).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was indeed the way the dnspython script would request the update of the zone.

Instead of requesting to add an entry `_acme-challenge.mail` to the `example.com` zone, it would instead (and wrongly) request an entry `_acme-challenge` to be added to the `mail.example.com` zone.

Since the nameserver had no `mail.example.com.` zone, it would refuse to handle the request.

The solution to the problem was to iteratively try adding to parent zones, until success (or the TLD has been reached):

- try adding `_acme-challenge` to zone `mail.example.com.`
- try adding `_acme-challenge.mail` to zone `example.com.`
- try adding `_acme-challenge.mail.example` to zone `com.`
- fail.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think that anything is "wrong".

We wrote a script that goes thought our 1000's of domains to edit the dns file manually and then restart the DNS service.